# How do I simultaneously update unique keys in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, update, unique-constraint

```
CREATE TABLE widget (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  ordinal int NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

I have the data

```
 id | name | ordinal 
----+------+---------
  1 | A    |       1
  2 | B    |       2
  3 | C    |       3
```

I would like to update it to

```
 id | name | ordinal 
----+------+---------
  1 | A    |       3
  2 | B    |       2
  3 | C    |       1
```

Touching records as little as possible (i.e. don't rewrite the entire record set, don't kick off unnecessary triggers), what's the generally applicable approach to updating `ordinal` to be the target values?

A vanilla update just gives me constraint violations, even if it happens in a single statement.

And dropping and recreating the unique constraint is expensive and poor concurrency.

This seems like a common enough problem that there ought to be a good way to do this, that I just can't think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the constraint as deferrable:

```
CREATE TABLE widget (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  ordinal int NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFERRABLE
);
```

Then you can update it in one statement:

```
update widget
  set ordinal = t.new_ordinal
from (
  values (1, 3), (3,1) 
) as t(id, new_ordinal)
where t.id = widget.id
```

Answer (score 6):

A plain `UNIQUE` constraint is `NOT DEFERRABLE` by default. Unique violations are checked ***after each row***. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) phrases this as:

> checked immediately after every command

But it's really checked for every individual written row.

If you define the `UNIQUE` constraint `DEFERRABLE` (like a_horse provided), unique violations are checked ***after each statement***. Multiple CTEs within the same query still count as a single *statement* in this respect.

```
CREATE TABLE widget_deferrable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  ordinal int NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFERRABLE  -- !
);
```

If you also actually set the constraint as `DEFERRED`, the check for unique violations is deferred until ***after each transaction***.

```
CREATE TABLE widget_deferred (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  ordinal int NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED  --!
);
```

Comprehensive demo:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a9c20041f15929cd8e0be88c6c2fcc6a)*

Further reading:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035119/939860)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer because it's the way I solved this problem, and I found this question when I was looking for answers. If your constraint was not marked `deferrable` when you created it, and you don't have the luxury of modifying the table, there is a workaround using CTEs.

```
with z as (
    select 1 as id, -1 as ordinal
    union select 3, 1
    union select 1, 3
)
update widget
set ordinal = z.ordinal
from z
where widget.id = z.id
```

This requires the rows in the CTE to come out in the exact order they are defined. I think this example will work, but I could be wrong. If it does not work, you may have to assign a bogus value to each row first, followed by a correct value. It's a bit weird, but it shouldn't take long to get used to.